# How to reinstate the Blazor WASM "offline-cache" after a cleanup of the caches?

Tags: javascript, c#, blazor, blazor-webassembly

Basically I have an upgrade flow where between localStorage and IndexedDB cleanups I perform also a caches cleanup:

```js
window.clearCache = async () => {
    const cachesNames = await caches.keys()
    for (let i = 0; i < cachesNames.length; i++)
        await caches.delete(cachesNames[i])
}
```

and after this I perform a `Navigation.NavigateTo(Navigation.Uri, forceLoad: true);` to force reload the website.

After this reload I have this situation where the usual `blazor-resources-/` if filled back automatically with all the resources meanwhile the `offline-cache-<random>` is still empty.

Is there a way to call again those steps that do cache those resources again?
[image: logs from service-worker of successful installation and activation]

Comment: Normally that would be part of the Install handler in the service worker - so normally, you update the service worker, and that controls clearing down and rebuilding it's cache as appropriate. outside of that flow, you would need to read in/build the list of offline assets and add them to the cache in much the same way the service worker would.

Comment: @MisterMagoo is there any concrete and full example on how to achieve it?
I also figured out from a [github](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/38495) issue that I opened that such reloading will not be pursued unfortunately :/

Comment: Do you have a sample project that replicates this? it is easier to offer a patch to your solution

Comment: @Mason.Chase nope, but it's not different than starting a new project and add a `clearCache` function to call like below and then forceReload the page
```js
window.clearCache = async () => {
 const cachesNames = await caches.keys()
 for (let i = 0; i < cachesNames.length; i++)
  await caches.delete(cachesNames[i])
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you are not invalidating the service worker and following the "normal" update flow?

Comment: @MisterMagoo could you point me what's a "normal" update flow?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/lifecycle#updates describes the process. You publish a new service worker that is different to the existing one (e.g. update the cache name/version) - the browser will then start the update process and when the new service worker is activated, it clears out the old cache and creates a new one. If you are using the Blazor service worker, it handles modifying the service worker when you publish so the user will start the update process next time the browser fetches the service worker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To *reinstate* the offline WASM cache, please  different strategy. I would *recommend* a different strategy and force a cache reload, using the CACHE_VERSION & .

> Step 1: Create a new `js` file

> Step 2: register it in `navigator.serviceWorker` object.

For e.g. `yourCustomCacheTriggerReloader.js` file should have a variable like

```
 // use this variable to update and trigger your forced upload
 // to the client after you delete you files.
 `const CACHE_VERSION = 1.0`.
```

> Step 3: when you delete, in your script/or manually, please update `CACHE_VERSION` value. That will tell/force the browser/client to `reload` the latest files.

---

Example from [here](https://www.eugenechiang.com/2021/05/22/forcing-reload-of-blazor-client-after-publishing-changes/):

```
// In service-worker.published.js
const CACHE_VERSION = '2021.05.22.001'  // Increment each time before deployment.
const cacheNamePrefix = 'offline-cache-';
const cacheName = `${cacheNamePrefix}${CACHE_VERSION}`;
```

---

```
//Note: The original one does not work. Replace 
//self.assetsManifest.version withCACHE_VERSION
const cacheName = ${cacheNamePrefix}${self.assetsManifest.version};
```

Comment: just a code typo: `\`${cacheNamePrefix}${self.assetsManifest.version}\``

Comment: thanks @Eugene will make that change gr8 Question, welcome to Stack Overflow :) BTW, feel free to edit the answer, you will get credit for that... they all add up _very slowly_